# If $\text{Arg}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\text{Arg}z_1-\text{Arg}z_2$, then $-\pi<\text{Arg}z_1-\text{Arg}z_2\le\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've proved this:

If $-\pi<\text{Arg}z_1-\text{Arg}z_2\le\pi$, then $\text{Arg}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\text{Arg}z_1-\text{Arg}z_2$

But I am look for a counterexample to show that this is false.

If $\text{Arg}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\text{Arg}z_1-\text{Arg}z_2$, then $-\pi<\text{Arg}z_1-\text{Arg}z_2\le\pi$

Can someone give me a counterexample?

Thanks.

Comment: There can be no counterexample if you define $\text{Arg}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)$ as the principle value in the range $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\operatorname{Arg}$ denotes the principle value of the argument in the range $(-\pi, \pi]$: For $z_1, z_2 \ne 0$ is
$$
\phi = \operatorname{Arg}z_1-\operatorname{Arg}z_2
$$
*some* argument of $z_1/z_2$. $\phi$ is the priniciple value of the argument of $z_1/z_2$ if (and only if) $\phi \in (-\pi, \pi]$. Therefore 
$$
\operatorname{Arg}\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\operatorname{Arg}z_1-\operatorname{Arg}z_2 \\
\iff -\pi < \operatorname{Arg}z_1-\operatorname{Arg}z_2 \le \pi \, .
$$